# Creating subnets

Tags: ip, subnet

Using the following IP Range can anyone break this down into 3 subnets for me displaying IP's in each range and their subnet masks please
Current setting below needs breaking into 3 the start off the range needs to be the smallest subnet.

IP Range 192.168.1.128 - 192.168.1.159
Gateway 192.168.1.129
Subnet 255.255.255.224
Usable 192.168.1.132 - 192.168.1.158

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the SubNetMask 255.255.255.248 you should quarter the IP-Range. So the new nets are:

1) IP: 192.168.1.128 
Usable: 192.168.1.129 - 192.168.1.134 (.135 is Broadcast)

2) IP: 192.168.1.136
Usable: 192.168.1.137 - 192.168.1.142 (.143 is Broadcast)

3) IP: 192.168.1.144 
Usable: 192.168.1.145 - 192.168.1.150 (.151 is Broadcast)

4) IP: 192.168.1.152 
Usable: 192.168.1.153 - 192.168.1.158 (.159 is Broadcast)